# JSON convert into string format

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I have a requirement like convert JSON data into string can you please help me on this.

My JSON data from service:

```
{
    "chathistory": [
        {
            "broadcastId": "123",
            "caption": "",
            "chattype": "CHAT_SINGLE",
            "delivered": "2015-03-23T10:20",
            "duration": "0"
        },
        {
            "broadcastId": "124",
            "caption": "",
            "chattype": "CHAT_SINGLE",
            "delivered": "2015-03-23T10:20",
            "duration": "5"
        }
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

I need to convert it like the below format

```
chathistory: [
    {
        broadcastId: '123',
        caption: '',
        chattype: 'CHAT_SINGLE',
        delivered: '2015-03-23T10: 20',
        duration: '0'
    },
    {
        broadcastId: '124',
        caption: '',
        chattype: 'CHAT_SINGLE',
        delivered: '2015-03-23T10: 30',
        duration: '5'
    }
]
```

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: Whata have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Json *is* a string. You have one string that you want to convert to another string based on what? The code you posted shows only the removal of the surrounding brackets and the omission of a couple of fields

Comment: Please post the code you used. Are you receiving Json as a string or is it deserialized to an object? Which libraries are you using? Moreover, WHY do you want to change the string's contents? Both strings can be parsed as Json, saved to a database etc so there should be no need for the change